# Pourquoi peut-on avoir deux « ne » dans la même phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, négation

[Ici](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/45535/filename/chapitre1.htm) (une étude sur les langues des signes), il y a deux phrases :

> Un des principaux reproches qu’adressent à la langue des signes ses détracteurs est son caractère purement figuratif et, de fait, son incapacité à représenter l’abstraction. Nous allons de suite voir qu’il **n’en n’est rien**.

Dans la partie marquée, pourquoi a-t-on deux « *ne* » à la suite ? Je crois qu'un « *ne* » suffit pour exprimer la négation…

Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est en fait une faute: la forme correcte est *il n'en est rien*. C'est une faute courante, parce qu'à l'oral, on fait la liaison entre "en" et "est", ce qui induit à penser qu'il doit y avoir un "ne" entre les deux mots.